# python count number of ones in a binary image

Tags: python, scipy

What is the python module to count number of ones in a binary image ?

to rephrase,

I have a matrix that has only ones and zeros, it's of numpy array type and I want to know how many ones are there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `sum`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> n = numpy.random.randint(0, 2, size=(3,3))
>>> n
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
>>> n.sum()
7
```

Since bools have integer values of 0/1 for False/True, even if the array had elements that weren't 0 or 1 you could use a variant of this trick:

```
>>> n = numpy.random.randint(0, 3, size=(3,3))
>>> n
array([[2, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])
>>> n == 1
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> (n == 1).sum()
2
```

Answer (score 2):

np.count_nonzero() works too, for binary matrix.

```
In [1]: n = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(3,3))

In [2]: n
Out[2]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])

In [3]: np.count_nonzero(n)
Out[3]: 4
```

This would be useful if 0 means False; otherwise True.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 1's and 0's you can just add them all together:

```
import numpy as np
import operator as op

count_of_ones = reduce(op.add, np.ravel(your_array))
```

Comment: reduce in python3 is considered obsolete by guido and moved to functools if im not mistaken

Comment: @DonQuestion is correct. However, it still does have use, and it is indeed in `functools` - the 2to3 tool rewrites it anyway and in some version of 2.x (maybe 2.7) `reduce` and `functools.reduce` are exactly the same thing. I don't think it's disappearing as a builtin until 3.4 or something (but don't quote me on that one!)

Answer (score 0):

For a very more efficient way to do it (as compared to the sum() approach), you are better using indexing. For exemple:

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now()        
sum(spindle_gold)
b = datetime.datetime.now()
len(spindle_gold[(spindle_gold).astype(bool) ] )
c = datetime.datetime.now()
```

gives

```
0:00:02.155000 0:00:00.025000 3870970
```

This method is therefore about 100 times faster. It's a good approach if you are using very large array and need good performances.